# How to Programmatically Build a TemplateColumn

Tags: asp.net

How does one go about programatically building a TemplateColumn object and adding it to a DataGrid.  I know how to add it, but not how to build the contents of the TemplateColumn.  There are no useful looking methods on the ITemplate the column class exposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CompiledTemplateBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.compiledtemplatebuilder.aspx) Class.

Here is an example:

http://iridescence.no/post/Using-Templated-Controls-Programmatically.aspx